# Correct way to link a .css file into JSF 2.2?

Tags: css, netbeans, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am still learning using JSF.

I am developing a .xhtml page in Netbeans 8 and I have some problems linking my .css files.

The css do not seems to be working.

**Update :
I follow the solution another similar question and created the resources folder and copy my folders into the resources.**

A small part of my code snippet is below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <head jsf:id = "head">
        <title>Limo - HTML5 E-Commerce Template</title>
        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" jsf:name="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="icon" jsf:name="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <!--Master Slider Styles-->

        <h:outputStylesheet name="masterslider/style/masterslider.css" />
        <!--Styles-->
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
        <script jsf:target="body" jsf:name="js/libs/modernizr.custom.js"/>
    </head>
```

This is how my folder structure looks like.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/41t90TB.png]

My CSS seems to be broken now..
Any idea why?

Thanks. :)

Comment: hi there. I have updated my question. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: You have `styles.css` in your folder structure and `style.css` in `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />`